# how to show hint in form in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show hint in my form .Actually I am using dform plugin .So I googled it and find how to show hint jquery .I found one solution in this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/xWCTf/19/
Please check this fiddle click on input will show hint
I apply same concept in my fiddle I used both dform and tooltip.js as used above .But my tooltip or hint not appear in fiddle.can you please tell why it is not display .?
here is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/48v3u/1/

```
/* simple css-based tooltip */
.tooltip {
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;

    /* outline radius for mozilla/firefox only */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
}

$("#testSuiteConfigurationform :input").tooltip({

    // place tooltip on the right edge
    position: "center right",

    // a little tweaking of the position
    offset: [-2, 10],

    // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
    effect: "fade",

    // custom opacity setting
    opacity: 0.7

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JqueryUI you can do it like this:

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
     $(document).tooltip();
   });
 </script>
```

And add title to Input Type:

```
<input id="age" title="Your hint goes here.">
```

Make sure you have added JqueryUI & Jquery file reference.

Comment: can you make fiddle ..or change my fiddle

Comment: You can also refer to here http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ for JQueryUI documentation